# Is it possible to upload multiple files in simple mode in Primefaces FileUploader?

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

In the  examples and showcase, fileUploadListener is always used in advance mode. I try to use it in simple mode but the uploadListener aren't called.

Is it valid?

```
<p:fileUpload  multiple="true" fileUploadListener="#{formBean.handleFileUpload}"  mode="simple"/>
```

Note: I already set ajax "false" and form enctype "multipart/form-data".

Comment: As I understand it it is not possible, and the multiple-attribute is irrelevant for simple mode

Comment: sometimes (often) the answer is in the question. If things do not work, they are not supported. And if you read the documentation _"Multiple Uploads
Multiple uploads can be enabled using the multiple attribute so that multiple files can be selected 
from browser dialog. Multiple uploads are not supported in legacy browsers. **Note that multiple 
mode is for selection only, it does not send all files in one request. FileUpload component always 
uses a  new request for each file.**"_ it requires ajax and that is not for mode="simple".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kukeltje and Jaqen H'ghar are right. The answer is NO for Primefaces 5.2.